# Install Jenkins plugins using Docker image

Tags: docker, jenkins

Say we use a Docker image to run Jenkins with a container.
Is there a way to install plugins in the image so we don't have to re-install if we create a new Jenkins server?

Something like:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
RUN install jenkins-plugin-a
RUN install jenkins-plugin-b
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `plugins.txt` file which contains list of plugins and use it in `Dockerfile` -

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

It's there in the official documentation.

Ref - https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker  (Preinstalling plugins)

Sample plugins.txt - https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/tests/install-plugins/pluginsfile/plugins.txt

PS - I haven't tested it yet but it's supposed to work.